# How to force not to use conversion constructor in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I'm working on a project with matrices and I'm having a problem with overloaded operators.

I have declared these user-friendly input/output functions:

```
friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, MathMatrix& m); //keyboard input
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const MathMatrix& m); // screen output
friend std::ifstream& operator>>(std::ifstream& ifs, MathMatrix& m); // file input
friend std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& ofs, const MathMatrix& m); // file output
```

While defining the last one of them, in this simple piece of code, I am given an error and can't compile:

```
// file output
std::ofstream& operator<<(std::ofstream& ofs, const MathMatrix& m) {
    //put matrix dimension in first line
    ofs << m.n << std::endl;
    //put data in third line
    for (int i=0; i<m.n; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<m.n; j++) ofs << m(i,j) << " ";
        ofs << std::endl;
    }
    return ofs;
}
```

The errors is in `ofs << m.n` (and a similar one in `ofs << m(i,j)`). It says:

```
const MathMatrix &m
Error: more than one operator "<<" matches these operands:
    function "operator<<(std::ofstream &ofs, const MathMatrix &m)"
    function "std::basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>::operator<<(int _Val) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>]"
    operand types are std::ofstream << const int
```

After a while I thought that maybe the problem is that I have a `MathMatrix` constructor like `MathMatrix (int n)`, so the compiler could be trying to convert from `int n` to `MathMatrix(int n)`. I don't see why it would do that, but it's the only explanation I can think of, given the explanation the IDE gives.

Can you see what I am missing? Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: Why do you even need them? Does the output to a file has to be different?

Comment: Declare any unwanted conversion constructors as `explicit`.

Comment: What compiler are you using? Are you able to generate a simple test case that we can compile to see your exact error?

Comment: There's a reason: when I print to screen I'm not interested in printing the size, just the matrix. When I output to a file I want to print the size first, in case I want to read that data later.
I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Express, and it was fixed by declaring the constructor as explicit. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a subtlety in the overload resolution that leads to an ambiguity here between the selection of a function for the call `ofs << m.n`. Here's a short example that reproduces the problem:

```
struct Base
{
    void operator<<(int);
};

struct Derived : Base
{
};

struct converter
{
    converter(int);
};

void operator<<(Derived&, converter const&);

int main()
{
    const int i = 42;
    Derived d;
    d << i;
}
```

---

#### Why is the call ambiguous?

First, the member function `Base::operator<<` gets an additional parameter of type `Base&` just for overload resolution [over.match.funcs]/2

> The set of candidate functions can contain both member and non-member functions to be resolved against the same argument list. So that argument and parameter lists are comparable within this heterogeneous set, a member function is considered to have an extra parameter, called the *implicit object parameter*, which represents the object for which the member function has been called.

As the member function (even inherited in `Derived`) is a member function of `Base`, the parameter type is a `Base&`, not a `Derived`; see /4.

Therefore we compare

```
void operator<<(Base&, int);                  // #0
void operator<<(Derived&, converter const&);  // #1
```

The arguments of the call `d << i` are of type `Derived` (lvalue) and `const int`. Therefore:

1. for overload #0

   1. for the first argument, a derived-to-base conversion is required
   2. for the second argument, a qualification conversion is required (`const int` to `int`)
2. for overload #1

   1. for the first argument, Exact Match (no conversion)
   2. for the second argument, a qualification conversion followed by a user-defined conversion is required (`const int` to `int`, `int` to `converter`)

Conversion 1.1 is worse than conversion 2.1, but conversion 1.2 is better than conversion 2.2. Hence, the call is ambiguous.

---

#### How to resolve the ambiguity?

Either:

- (preferred) make the conversion in `MathMatrix` explicit
- only declare an `operator<<(std::ostream&, MathMatrix const&)`, but none for `std::ofstream` (this will make 1.1 equal to 1.2, therefore overload #1 becomes a better match)
- convert the `std::ofstream` in the call explicitly to the base class `std::ostream` (helps in a similar way to the previous version)
- hide the offending overload e.g. via a *using-declaration* `using std::operator<<;`

Answer (score 3):

If in your class you have a constructor with single argument with different type than your class, it can be used for implicit type conversion. To prevent that you just need to mark that constructor explicit:

```
class MathMatrix {
public:
   explicit MathMatrix( int m );
...
};
```

It is a good idea to always mark single argument constructor explicit (unless argument is the same class type or you do want such type conversion)

Comment: I don't think this is the answer.

Comment: @Skizz it should solve the compilation error. Does OP really need 2 versions of `operator<<` one for `std::ostream` and one for `std::ofstream` is different question.

Comment: Yep, missed that bit. This is the answer.